# where do I get arguments of win32 API function CallWindowProc()?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

According to my research, when I run C# executable which opens WinForm, within .NET, they don't offer the function to access those WinForm object from separate c# process (separate file I mean) but win32 API does.

Then I came across 3 functions from API.

```
FindWindow();
GetWindowLong();
CallWindowProc()
```

I need to call it from top down to the bottom but then I got stuck by `CallWIndowProc()` because
I can't figure what I should pass for last 3 arguments.

```
private static extern UIntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr a, IntPtr b, uint c, IntPtr d, IntPtr e);

c, d and e
```

According to the doc, it should be some sort of "message" which is int. But where can I get such value???

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633571(v=vs.85).aspx

**Code:**

```
 [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
 private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);
 [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
 private static extern long GetWindowLong(IntPtr a, int b);
 [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
 private static extern UIntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr a, IntPtr b, uint c, IntPtr d, IntPtr e);

 [STAThread]
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    IntPtr lResult;
    uint lMsg = 0;
    IntPtr HWND = FindWindow("WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1", "Form1");
    int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
    long WNDPROC = GetWindowLong(HWND, GWL_WNDPROC);
    lResult = CallWindowProc(WNDPROC, HWND, lMsg, 0, 0);
 }
```

**Clarification**

OK.. I should have made it clear.. my goal is to run following chunk of code against the WebForm being executed. (I'ts WatiN)

```
var t = new Thread(() =>
{
  Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
  var ie = new IE(form1.webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);
  ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
  ie.TextField(Find.ByClass("lst")).TypeText("this is awesome!!");
  ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I run myCSharpCode.exe which opens WinForm. Then I want separate otherCSharp.cs to be able to access to, say, textbox in the WinForm.

Comment: Doing it this way will not work. You need to use SendMessage/PostMessage instead. Doing that cross thread and particularly cross process is hard to get right, so I suggest you read up on Win32 messaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What message you are trying to send to callWinProc?

Arguments are

nProc is a value returned previously by SubClassWindow() (Source Window).

hWnd is the handle to the window that was subclassed (target window).

nMsg is the message (one of the WM_* values defined in WINDOWS.CH, basically kind of event or message like click is one message). For complete system messages see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#system_defined

wParam depends on nMsg. For click, it takes left or right click

lParam depends on nMsg. for click it takes the location as lparam

you can see wparam and lparam defination for each message.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to call the window proc of a window from a different thread/process. I'm assuming this because you're using FindWindow, and I can't see where you created the window. If that is what you are doing, CallWindowProc won't work because you cannot call a window proc from a thread other than the one that created the window. What you need is SendMessage, which accepts the same last four parameters (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) - to interpret them you need to know what message you're sending.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand to use the parameter names from the native methode just for clearness. You can get those pinvoke signatures from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) so you don't have to do it on your own all the time. These messages are definded in header files and documented in the msdn. Its quiete hard to use the right message in the correct manner if you're new to win32 and/or C#.

If you want to intercept the windows messages of your form you need a windows message hook, but this doesn't work in .Net. You can also read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) which cover this topic.

Maybe you should try to find a complete different solution for your problem. Other IPC methodes etc.

EDIT: The CLR type of your form (WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1) is not the class name you have to put in FindWindow, FindWindow is an unmanaged api and isn't aware of the CLR typesystem. Try out Spy++ to investigate some windows on your PC.

Comment: This doesn't look like subclassing to me - there is no call to SetWindowLong here